Spring Boot Rest - How to map headers to a DTO
i'm using Spring Boot and need to access multiple values from the request headers, the problem is that @RequestHeader it only accepts a single property at a time. Instead of declaring individual properties each time, I'd like to convert this into a DTO for better organization.
Using query params i can use @ModelAttribute filters: FiltersDTO and that works, Is there an equivalent approach for handling request headers, where I can map them to a DTO directly?
That is my code:
@PostMapping("blah")
suspend fun blah(
  @RequestHeader userInfo: UserHeaderDto
) {}

data class UserHeaderDto(
    val userId: Long,
    val name: String
){}

I receive the exception:
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'userInfo' for method parameter type UserHeaderDto is not present


Does this answer your question? springframework get all request headers

No, using Map allows me to have all headers values but i still need to convert them manually to my DTO, i want some solution that spring do this automatically like with query params using ModelAttribute

Try using a Map<String, String> headers, and then you can have a class called RequestHeadersExtractor that encapsulates the logic of extracting the request headers.
Take a look at the below example:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RequestHeadersExtractor {
// declare your request headers
    public static final String USER_ID = "user-id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";

    public SampleDto extractHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {

    // populate your dto here with the fields and return it.

    }
}

Then you can call extractHeaders from your controller's method.
